# Random Black Block in the background

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image: Intruding black shape]

Hi

I'm new to Blender and I've been practicing by creating a model of a monitor with a screen that shows a image of a piece of software.

When I preview or render the animation there is an odd black shape that is cutting through the ground object and backdrop cylinder object (see left of attached image) but not in my stage (right side of image). It changes shape as the camera moves around so I thought it could be a random shadow being created but cannot work it out.

Thanks in advance.
James

Comment: are u rendering in Cycles? does it also appear when rendering in Eevee?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it was the clipping in the camera settings. Thanks for looking at my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the clipping settings in the cameraoptions. you can control how much of a scene is visible there.
You can change how far the camera sees here, same settings can be done for the viewport.
You need to click on the camera symbol in the outliner on the top-right to get option you want.
[image]

if you zoom out to much without your camera active, and suddenly your scene disappears, the settings are found in the viewtab on the right side.
[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking, thanks